# Communication between EC2 servers for seperate services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What would be the best architecture to communicate the share the processing between EC2 instance?

For example, I have one EC2 server for API. And I need to process images received from API.

So, what is the best way to send the photo received from API to another server to process it?

Should I upload to S3 and then grab from S3 to process it?

I need to access the image uploaded fairly quickly.

Comment: You should test this.  As long as you always use a new "key" (that's the S3 term for path+filename -- do not overwrite an existing object in S3) you should find this to be a fast and viable solution which, as @helloV correctly suggests, also provides assurance that the files should never be "lost."  Overwriting objects in S3 by reusing keys does not carry the same assurance that an immediate read-after-write will always return the newly-written copy.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the size of the photos, the volume of photos, the speed you want to process, it is difficult to suggest a solution. S3 solution is better since the photos are stored and can be processed in batch. Even if computing fails for some reason, you are assured the photos are not lost.

If the number of photos that are uploaded is small, you can consider using AWS Lambda. Whenever a photo is uploaded, it will trigger a lambda function which will process the photo and store it in a different bucket.

Comment: Hi, I saw that lambda isn't available in my region. For using S3, I believe the steps are 1. upload to s3, 2. notify image_processing service 3. processed it and save. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. In fact the AWS lambda example tries to solve your problem. It tries to create a thumbnail of the uploaded image.